# Split file by date column value

Tags: file, date, csv, awk, split

I have a csv file that has 89 columns and it contains multiple dates of data. The date column is the 59th column. The date format is `mm/dd/yy`. What I would like to achieve is to create a file with `mmddyyyy.csv`, so each file will contain only one date of data.

So far my approach is

1. Get all distinct date from files
2. For each distinct date

   ```
   grep [date value] file > mmddyyyy.csv
   ```

The only drawback of the above solution is that if `[date value]` exists anywhere in the line, it will be picked up and I possibly will end up with one record in two or more files.

I know for a single value (string/number) awk can do it straight forward like

```
awk -F"\t" '{print >> ($14".csv");}' $1
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like all you need is:

```
awk -F, '{split($59,t,"/"); print > (t[1] t[2] "20" t[3] ".csv")}' file
```

but without sample input and expected output it's a guess. If you're not using GNU awk you might need to throw in a `close()` when appropriate to avoid having too many files open simultaneously.